# pandas plot line segments for each row

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframes with columns containing x,y coordinates for multiple points. One row can consist of several points.
I'm trying to find out an easy way to be able to plot lines between each point generating a curve for each row of data.

Here is a simplified example where two lines are represented by two points each.

```
line1 = {'p1_x':1, 'p1_y':10, 'p2_x':2, 'p2_y':11 }
line2 = {'p1_x':2, 'p1_y':9, 'p2_x':3, 'p2_y':12 }
df = pd.DataFrame([line1,line2])

df.plot(y=['p1_y','p2_y'], x=['p1_x','p2_x'])
```

when trying to plot them I expect line 1 to start where x=1 and line 2 to start where x=2.
Instead, the x axis contains two value-pairs (1,2) and (2,3) and both lines have the same start and end-point in x-axis.

How do I get around this problem?

Edit:
If using matplotlib, the following hardcoded values generates the plot i'm interested in
    plt.plot([[1,2],[2,3]],[[10,9],[11,12]])

Comment: Maybe all you wanted was `df.T.plot()`

Answer (score 3):

While I'm sure that there should be a more succinct way using pure pandas, here's a simple approach using `matplotlib` and some derivatives from the original `df`.(I hope I understood the question correctly)

Assumption: In `df`, you place `x` values in even columns and `y` values in odd columns

Obtain `x` values

```
x = df.loc[:, df.columns[::2]]
x

    p1_x    p2_x
0   1   2
1   2   3
```

Obtain `y` values

```
y = df.loc[:, df.columns[1::2]]
y

    p1_y    p2_y
0   10  11
1   9   12
```

Then plot using a for loop

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    plt.plot(x.iloc[i,:], y.iloc[i,:])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! yes, that is what I wanted to do!

Comment: Glad could be of help. I feel that there must be a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

One does not need to create additional data frames. One can loop through the rows to plot these lines:

```
line1 = {'p1_x':1, 'p1_y':10, 'p2_x':2, 'p2_y':11 }
line2 = {'p1_x':2, 'p1_y':9, 'p2_x':3, 'p2_y':12 }
df = pd.DataFrame([line1,line2])

for i in range(len(df)):   # for each row:
    # plt.plot([list of Xs], [list of Ys])
    plt.plot([df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,2]],[df.iloc[i,1],df.iloc[i,3]])
plt.show()
```

The lines will be drawn in different colors. To get lines of same color, one can add option `c='k'` or whatever color one wants.

```
plt.plot([df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,2]],[df.iloc[i,1],df.iloc[i,3]], c='k')
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I generaly don't use the pandas plotting because I think it is rather limited, if using matplotlib is not an issue, the following code works:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.p1_x,df.p1_y)
plt.plot(df.p2_x,df.p2_y)
plt.plot()
```

if you got lots of lines to plot, you can use a for loop.

Comment: Guess what pandas plotting is from matplotlib, if you see here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html they say `Make plots of DataFrame using matplotlib / pylab.`

Comment: thanks for the help, but Unfortunately this is not a solution. I need a line between p1, and p2 for each row. Your first plot connects all p1 for every row.

Comment: @Dangraf Ok! missunderstood the question